# I uninstalled unity and now I don't have any desktop environment

Tags: gnome, unity

I was testing Unity, but didn't like it. When I got rid of it there was nothing there, just a big white screen.

When I tried to apt-get gnome it gave me this error:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies: 
 gnome: Depends: swfdec-mozilla but it is not going to be installed
E: Broken packages
```

Comment: 10.10 or 11.04?

Comment: I think he is on Natty

Answer (score 1):

This may do it:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop
```

Don't forget to logout and log back in, or restart for all the changes to appear.

Comment: So i tried that and everything was successfuil, everything unpacked. But after I restart there are no changes. Also when i log out normally there is a bar at the bottom with option like which environment to use(desktop/netbook) and some other setting but it shows up blank 9/10 times. Also i'm using 10.10 thanks.

Comment: Sorry follow up. I reinstalled Unity just so i could get some kind of environment and it seems like unity might be the default. On the log in screen where i can choose the environment it only lets me choose desktop/notebook, shouldn't it let me choose GNOME/Unity?

Comment: @Nate Can you add all this information to your original question so it doesn't get buried in the comments? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

restart by pressing the power button, on the logon screen click on your account name and then select "Ubuntu desktop edition" instead of "Ubuntu Netbook Edition" from the third combo (left to right)... on the buttom of the logon screen